# Set CMYK colors in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cmyk, rgb

I have designed a Flyer using Photoshop. First with RGB colors, but I want to change them to CMYK.
I use black, white and two pantone colors.
Black is used for the text and there is the problem.

I select the text, <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd></kbd>, and select the color window in the option bar on top.

I have unchecked the `Only Web Colors` checkbox.

I enter `C0 M0 Y0 K100` and observe the RGB value in the same color box change to `R29 G29 B27`, the CMYK values are still `C0 M0 Y0 K100`, so I press OK and apply in the option bar.

Next I reopen the color window in the option bar on top to check the color values.
I see the CMYK values are not as I entered before but they are `C75 M65 Y62 K81`.
The RGB values are the same as before, `R29 G29 B27`.

It seems the CYMK values are converted to RGB and the CMYK values are discarded.
Whatever I do, I can't have the desired result.

Which setting do I have to change to allow CMYK in Text?

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to change the `Color Mode` via `Image > Mode > CMYK Color`.

[image: Change Color Mode Photoshop CS5]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this: `Edit`> `Convert to profile`.

This way you can fine tune your CMYK settings, and you will not loose any layers. However, if something will be CMYK it's better to start in CMYK, to avoid any color shifts, which can happen even if your RGB colors are within the CMYK range. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this is just half the solution! Making something in RGB color format and then changing it to CMYK as answered here merges all the layers and makes them unavailable for further use. What I suggest is make another document with the same canvas size and image size in CMYK color mode and then select all the layers in the document with RGB format and then just drag-drop them in the document with CMYK format. That will auto change all the layers to CMYK and also make them available for further use without merging them.